# Como filtrar usando la edad de una persona en angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Intente hacer con esto, pero no funciono:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="universidadApp">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Filtros - ng-repeat</title>
        <!-- Incluir Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Animate.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
        <!-- Incluir AngularJS -->
        <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <style>
            .avatar{
                width: 75px;
                height: 75px;
            }

            .puntero{
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-controller="listadoCtrl">          
            <h1>Filtros</h1>
            <h4>Para el ng-repeat</h4>
            <hr>          
            <div class="row">
                Busqueda:
                <br>
                <input type="text" ng-model="busqueda.nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese lo que desea buscar.">            
                <br>

                Sexo:
                <br>
                <select ng-model="busqueda.sexo" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Cualquiera</option>
                    <option value="mujer">Mujeres</option>
                    <option value="hombre">Hombres</option>
                </select>
                <br>
            </div>
            Age Range <input type="number" name="filterAgeMin" ng-model="filterModelMin.edad" /> to <input type="number" name="filterAgeMax" ng-model="filterModelMax.edad" /><br><br>
            {{filterModelMin.edad}}
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Avatar</th>
                    <th> <a class="puntero" ng-click="columna='nombre'; reverse = !reverse;"> Nombre</a> </th>
                    <th> <a class="puntero" ng-click="columna='sexo'; reverse = !reverse;"> Sexo</a></th>
                    <th>Teléfono</th>
                    <th>Celular</th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="persona in persona| filter:byRange('edad', filterModelMin.edad, filterModelMax.edad)| orderBy:columna:reverse ">
                    <td> <img ng-src="img/{{ persona.avatar }}" class="avatar img-circle"> </td>
                    <td> {{ persona.nombre }} </td>
                    <td> {{ persona.sexo }}</td>
                    <td> {{ persona.telefono }}</td>
                    <td> {{ persona.celular }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div><!-- fin del listadoCtrl -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Archivo **JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('universidadApp',[ ]);
app.controller('listadoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.byRange = function (fieldName, minValue, maxValue) {
        if (minValue === undefined) minValue = Number.MIN_VALUE;
        if (maxValue === undefined) maxValue = Number.MAX_VALUE;

        return function predicateFunc(item) {
          return minValue <= item[fieldName] && item[fieldName] <= maxValue;
        };
      };
    $scope.personas=[
      {
        "id": 0,
        "sexo": "hombre",
        "nombre": "Kari Carr",
        "avatar": "kari.jpg",
        "telefono": "(826) 453-3497",
        "edad":10,
        "celular": "(801) 9175-8136"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "sexo": "mujer",
        "nombre": "Tameka Gamble",
        "avatar": "tameka.jpg",
        "telefono": "(824) 438-2499",
         "edad":20,
        "celular": "(801) 8595-8337"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "sexo": "mujer",
        "nombre": "Charity Austin",
        "avatar": "charity.jpg",
        "telefono": "(817) 512-2258",
         "edad":35,
        "celular": "(801) 9375-3830"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "sexo": "mujer",
        "nombre": "Slater Hunt",
        "avatar": "slater.jpg",
        "telefono": "(842) 413-3023",
         "edad":35,
        "celular": "(801) 9555-1729"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "sexo": "mujer",
        "nombre": "Chen Hanson",
        "avatar": "chen.jpg",
        "telefono": "(966) 520-2696",
         "edad":26,
        "celular": "(801) 9324-4423"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "sexo": "hombre",
        "nombre": "Obrien Davis",
        "avatar": "obrien.jpg",
        "telefono": "(996) 595-3896",
         "edad":30,
        "celular": "(801) 8195-2732"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "sexo": "hombre",
        "nombre": "Le Haley",
        "avatar": "le.jpg",
        "telefono": "(967) 527-3286",
         "edad":24,
        "celular": "(801) 8074-5225"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "sexo": "hombre",
        "nombre": "Lester Carney",
        "avatar": "lester.jpg",
        "telefono": "(994) 465-3542",
         "edad":22,
        "celular": "(801) 9044-7522"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "sexo": "hombre",
        "nombre": "Rosario Perry",
        "avatar": "rosario.jpg",
        "telefono": "(848) 499-2977",
         "edad":21,
        "celular": "(801) 8495-0625"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "sexo": "mujer",
        "nombre": "Marilyn Huber",
        "avatar": "marilyn.jpg",
        "telefono": "(982) 580-3235",
         "edad":20,
        "celular": "(801) 8184-2624"
      }
    ];
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A primera vista veo que estas aplicando mal el `ng-repeat`, te comiste una 'S' en persona**s**

Tendría que quedarte así:

```
<tr ng-repeat="persona in personas| filter:byRange('edad', filterModelMin.edad, filterModelMax.edad)| orderBy:columna:reverse ">
```